# Setting up an Internal DNS Server, Inherited a Workgroup Environment

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm currently getting ready to move my company to a domain, they are on a workgroup using their IP's DNS servers. I need to have users resolve internal addresses and thinking about using a Forwarder to resolve external addresses as needed. No external users need to use this DNS server to resolve anything, it will be used for internal users behind the firewall only. So my predecessor said I would need to register my DNS server (w/an outside agency)if I was gonna have an internal DNS server in AD. I don't believe this is true, but correct me if I'm wrong?  Do I need to do any special "registering" of the internal DNS server if I just need it to resolve internal requests & set up a forward on it for external resolutions?

What do I really need to do to get this DNS server up & running!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to do any special "registering" of the internal DNS server
>   if I just need it to resolve internal requests & set up a forward on
>   it for external resolutions?

No.

What they may have been referring to is the current Microsoft best practice recommendation of using an unused subdomain of your external domain name for your internal AD DNS namespace. Think ***ad.example.com***, for instance.

If you're creating an Active Directory domain then install the DNS server role along with the AD DS role and the domain creation process (DCPROMO) will create and configure the DNS namespace/zone as part of the domain creation process.

Comment: Joeqwerty, 1st thanks for your time! So, i just need to install the AD & DNS role on my Win 2016 server & put a Forwarder in the DNS e.g. 8.8.8.8 and all my users should be able to resolve any boxes internally as well as any address externally being the forwarder &  that is it!!?

Thanks again

Comment: Pretty much, yes.